# PHP Function for Comparing Elements in Different Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like so **(however there can be more or less than 2 (any amount))**:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [assessedUsers] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [scores] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 10
                                [1] => 10
                                [2] => 10
                                [3] => 10
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [scores] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 9
                                [1] => 10
                                [2] => 0
                                [3] => 9
                            )

                    )
            )
    )
```

Where the length of the scores array is always the same in both arrays.

**I would like to take each element from each array, one by one, and average them, then append them into a new array.**

For example, the output of my desired function would look like this:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [scores] => Array
            (
                [0] => 9.5
                [1] => 10
                [2] => 5
                [3] => 9.5
            )

    )
```

**Is there a function that can do this, or do I need a couple nested `for()` loops? If I need to use  `for`l loops how would I go about doing it? I'm a little confused on the logic behind it.**

Currently what I have is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data["assessedUsers"]); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($data["assessedUsers"][$i]["scores"]); $j++) {

    }
}
```

and I'm a little confused as to what to where to go next. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need some loops.

Comment: Do you have only two array or there might be more?

Comment: There could and will be more.

Comment: @php than you should state it in your question

Answer (score 1):

```
$mean = array_map( function($a, $b) { return ($a + $b) / 2; },
          $data['assessedUsers'][0]['scores'],
          $data['assessedUsers'][1]['scores']
        );

var_dump($mean);
```

And append `$mean` anywhere you want. Or do you have more than 2 arrays? You did not state it in your question.

ps: for any number of subarrays

```
$arr = array(
   array('scores' => array(10,10,10,10)),
   array('scores' => array(9,10,0,9)),
   array('scores' => array(1,2,3,4))
);

// remove arrays from the key
$tmp = call_user_func_array( function() { return func_get_args(); }, 
  array_map( function($a) { return $a['scores']; }, $arr)
);

// add arrays by each element
$mean = array_map( function($val, $ind) use($tmp) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($tmp as $i => $t)
       $sum += $t[$ind];
    return $sum / ($i + 1); 
}, $tmp[0], array_keys($tmp[0]));

var_dump($mean);
```

Comment: @php there is no 500.. only if you are using a very old php. what version do you have?

Comment: There also can be more than 2 arrays.

Comment: Well there is haha. I'm looking at the error right now. It's through Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Probably two loops:

```
$newarray();

foreach($main_array as $user) {
   foreach($user['assessedUser'][0]['scores'] as $score_key => $user0_value) {
           $user1_value = $user['assessedUser'][1]['scores'][$score_key];
           $average = ($user1_value + $user0_value) / 2;
           ... stuff into new array
   }
}
```

Comment: There will be more than two arrays. I don't know what the length is.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for you, hope this help :)

```
$scores = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data["assessedUsers"]); $i++) {       
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($data["assessedUsers"][$i]["scores"]); $j++) {
        if(isset($scores[$j])){
            $scores[$j] = ($scores[$j] + $data["assessedUsers"][$i]["scores"][$j]) / ($i +1);
        }else{
            $scores[] = $data["assessedUsers"][$i]["scores"][$j];
        }
    }
}
```

> $scores[] = $scores;

view Example :) 
http://codepad.org/upPjMEym

Comment: 500 internal server error. I don't think some of that is proper PHP syntax.

Comment: check **Array();** or **array()** check update answer

Comment: Pretty sure it's not only that it should be `$scores = array();` but it shouldn't be `$scores[]`, because I'm still getting 500 internal server error.

Comment: I don't have any IDE for php, so i thing error in **$scores = array();**
replace **Array()** to **array()**

Comment: this **/ $i +1** change to **/($i +1)** this error when $i = 0;

Comment: still 500 internal server error with your updated code

Comment: It's something with the if statement

Comment: are you sure this line: `if($scores[$j] != NULL){` shouldn't be the `$data` array?

Comment: sorry!!. use **isset()** :) check array null, check my updated answer :)

Comment: sorry!!. use isset() :) check array null, check my updated answer :)

Comment: Does the allow for an array of any length? Because it looks like this only allows for 2.

Comment: yes this allow for any array length. try with array of any length :). This will be ok